# Avoid OAuth token in source code?

Tags: javascript, java, php, api, oauth

I have to use my **OAuth2 token** in my API program.
But I also want to share my code via **GitHub**.
How can I use my secret **token** without having it in my source?

Comment: What do you mean `hide` ? Either token is there or it is not. You want to prevent search engines from indexing it or you want to delete the token automatically before pushing the code to github?

Comment: Does your project require *your* token specifically? Or would they like to use their own token?

Comment: It is just hide my token. There is no custom user token necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could require the token as a runtime argument for the application or you could store the token in a file that is not added to the repository.

For a file, you could store the API token in `token.txt` and then add `token.txt` to your `.gitignore`

This way you can have people who want to use your project just include their own API tokens without having to modify the code!

(If you're trying to hide or obfuscate your own token, that will probably be more effort than it's worth.)

Comment: Thanks. Using it as a runtime argument is the easiest thing which fulfill my requirements. Easy to implement and safe from source control.